# Core Image face detection gives zero faces - xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin.iOS app which use `Core Image face detection`[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/graphics-animation-ios/introduction-to-coreimage).I have a custom camera view and when we capture photo, I am doing some action if the image contains any face. The face detection works on most of the iPhones. When I tested on an old iPad with `iOs 10.3.4`, the face detection method gives zero face count even if I capture face.

**Face detection implementation**

```
private async Task FaceDetectionCheking(UIImage photo)
        {           
                try
                {
                    var imageFile = photo;                  
                    var context = new CIContext();
                    var detector = CIDetector.CreateFaceDetector(context, true);
                    var ciImage = CIImage.FromCGImage(imageFile.CGImage);
                    var features = detector.FeaturesInImage(ciImage);                   
                            
                    if (features.Length == 0)
                    {
                       // No face detected.
                    }
                    else if(features.Length == 1)
                    {
                        // Single face detected
                    }
                    else if(features.Length > 1)
                    {
                        // Multiple face detected !
                    }
                
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
        }
```

Is there any possibility of device does not support this face detection API? If that is the case how can I check whether it support or not? Any help is appriciated.

**Edit**

It might sound funny. Face detection works if we capture face of internet photos. Not mine. :D. But working on all other devices.

Comment: Does the detection fail on all your photos ? Did you try another photo?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT It fails to detect face  when I capture real person photos. But it will detect face when we scan any face image in google.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT and also it will not detect faces on all photos of google too. eg: It will detect face from this image https://www.thestatesman.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/1493458748-beauty-face-517.jpg

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT but not detecting this https://www.eaclinic.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/woman-face-eyes-1000x1000.jpg

Comment: It's weird, i will download the sample and check the result .

Comment: I test on ios14 iphone8 , the detection works on all the scenarios , the two images above works , and taking photos(from internet photos and real person) also works . I suggest you use this api on recent ios versions and make the face clear&visible on the photo.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT ok colex. Maybe it due to older os version